# Is the base game included with the Frozen Throne?

Tags: warcraft-3, warcraft-3-the-frozen-throne

If I buy Warcraft 3:The Frozen Throne, do I have to buy Warcraft 3 as well, or does that come with it?

Comment: I have removed your second question, since we try to keep questions to one per.  Feel free to ask a second question about the matchmaking service, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Warcraft 3: The Frozen Throne is an expansion to Warcraft 3 and requires you to purchase the original game as well.

Source - [Warcraft 3 Website](http://us.blizzard.com/en-us/games/war3/):

> Expansion requires the full version of Warcraft III

A "Battle Chest" is offered that includes both the original game and expansion.

Comment: Isn't "Battle Chest" a WoW thing and not a Warcraft thing? What "Battle Chest" are you referring to? And is it cheaper than buying both individually?

Comment: There is/was a Warcraft 3 Battle chest with the base game + expansion.